# Invalid relational operator in rawsql, same statement works in sqldeveloper

Tags: java, sql, exception, oracle-sqldeveloper, rawsql

This statement works perfectly when beeing executed in SQLDeveloper(Oracle DB).

```
select id,name,street,post_code,town,phone_number,web_site,email,short_description,    
description, latitude,longitude,external_id,facebook_page_id 
FROM poi WHERE ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( 5 ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos(    
radians( longitude ) - radians( 3 ) ) + sin( radians( 5 ) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) <= 1000000 ;
```

**If i execute it via a java query:**

```
if (requestedDistance) {
String raw = "SELECT         
id,name,street,post_code,town,phone_number,web_site,email,short_description, description,             
latitude,longitude,external_id,facebook_page_id"
+ " FROM poi WHERE ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( "
+ posLatitude.toString()
+ " ) ) * cos("
+ " radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) -"
+ " radians( "
+ posLongitude.toString()
+ " ) ) + sin( radians( "
+ posLatitude.toString()
+ " ) ) * sin( radians( latitude"
+ " ) ) ) ) <= "
+ thresholdDistance.toString() + " ;";
```

**the following exception is appearing in the logs:**

> ```
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Query threw
> ```
>
> SQLException:ORA-00920: invalid relational operator   Bind values:[] 
>   Query was: select
>   id,name,street,post_code,town,phone_number,web_site,email,short_description,
>   description, latitude,longitude,external_id,facebook_page_id  FROM poi
>   WHERE ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( 5 ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) )
>   * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians( 3 ) ) + sin( radians( 5 ) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) <= 1000000 ;
>
> ```
>     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQuery.createPersistenceException(CQuery.java:834)
>     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQuery.createPersistenceException(CQuery.java:814)
>     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQueryEngine.findMany(CQueryEngine.java:229)
>     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.DefaultOrmQueryEngine.findMany(DefaultOrmQueryEngine.java:96)
>     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.OrmQueryRequest.findList(OrmQueryRequest.java:291)
>     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.findList(DefaultServer.java:1521)
>     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.querydefn.DefaultOrmQuery.findList(DefaultOrmQuery.java:902)
>     at com.infonova.experimedia.services.ServiceController.getPois(ServiceController.java:113)
>     ... 34 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
>
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
>     at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.PreparedStatementWrapper40.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper40.java:642)
>     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQuery.prepareBindExecuteQuery(CQuery.java:401)
>     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQueryEngine.findMany(CQueryEngine.java:193)
>     ... 39 more
> ```
>
> |#]

copying the statement from the logfile and executing it in sqldeveloper again returns a valid output..

thanks for every help!

Nico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `;` at the end - it's the terminator character of SQLDeveloper/SQLPlus, not a part of SQL syntax.

Comment: Thanks a million, that was the solution. Will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-00920 invalid relational operator Cause: A search condition was
>   entered with an invalid or missing relational operator.
>
> Action: Include a valid relational operator such as =, !=, ^=, <>, >,
>   <, >=, <=, ALL, ANY, [NOT] BETWEEN, EXISTS, [NOT] IN, IS [NOT] NULL,
>   or [NOT] LIKE in the condition.

Comment: I found that too, but this didn't lead to the solution from Mureinik. 
Thanks anyway.